# Name for an exercise on chin-up bar with body rotation

Tags: warm-up, gymnastics, chin-ups

I can't find info/name for the following exercise/element done on a bar. You start by holding bar and hanging, than raising legs, bending them in knees, then pulling them above the head, and positioning them so you end up hanging on the opposite side. The same way is used to return to the beginning position.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "Positioning them so you end up hanging on the opposite side." Are you doing a back flip?

Comment: This could be a skin-the-cat.

Comment: Yes, dave, it's Skin the Cat! Thank you! :) If you wish put the info in the answer below, so I could mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a little vague, but it sounds like you are describing a [hanging pike](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/hanging-pike).

> 1. Hang from a chin-up bar with your legs and feet together using an overhand grip (palms facing away from you) that is slightly wider than shoulder width. Tip: You may use wrist wraps in order to facilitate holding on to the bar.
> 2. Now bend your knees at a 90 degree angle and bring the upper legs forward so that the calves are perpendicular to the floor while the thighs remain parallel to it. This will be your starting position.
> 3. Pull your legs up as you exhale until you almost touch your shins with the bar above you. **Tip:** Try to straighten your legs as much as possible while at the top.
> 4. Lower your legs as slowly as possible until you reach the starting position. Tip: Avoid swinging and using momentum at all times.
> 5. Repeat for the recommended amount of repetitions.